# Horitzontal scroll not shown

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.TFtable{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.TFtable td {
  padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
}
.TFtable tr {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
.TFtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
.TFtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #dae5f4;
}
```

to format an HTML table. However, the table is "broken" regarding the window width, cause it is too large, but the horizontal scroll bar is not shown.

What is it going on?

EDIT (HTML code):

```
  <body>
  <div class="mainbar">Sequentia Biotech Variant Query</div>
  <div class="outer">
  <table class="TFtable">
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Chromosome</td>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>002</td>
    </tr>
  <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].chr %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].pos %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].g001 %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].g002 %></td>
     </tr>
  <% } %>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please include your html markup.

Comment: Until you post the HTML you're using, my best guess is that the padding causes the width to exceed 100%. By default `width` refers to the size of the content, so maybe try `box-sizing: border-box` instead?